How do I get the existing "Tag" taxonomy to show on Wordpress Posts?
Visual Example of what I'm talking about.
I need to show the "Tags" taxonomy on the Posts for my website. I've already tried disabling every plugin and that didn't work.
I tried registering it as a taxonomy, but that overwrites them all and is blank, leaving me to recreate everything, and it's not even associated with the other tags. I put the following code in the functions.php file (under an existing function).
    $tag_labels = array(
        'name' => 'Post Tags',
        'singular_name' => 'Post Tag',
    );

    $tag_args = array(
        'labels' => $tag_labels,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'public' => true,
    );
register_taxonomy( 'post_tags', array('post'), $tag_args );

It overwrites the existing tags/doesn't associate them.
If the theme doesn't allow it, is there a way to register the "Tags" taxonomy and associate it to the  the existing tags already on there?
